Ubuntu 22.04 black boot screen
After my computer froze I rebooted it to find it was stuck at a black boot screen. From my research it sounds like it's due to a boot failure. I'm unsure of how to troubleshoot from this step. When I press Esc it shows me the background processes and says that some are failing. I'm trying to figure out the best way to address this problem in order to gain access to my desktop environment again.
Failed boot loading screen:

